# CSS Only Table with DIVs. How to NOT scroll the top row

Tags: html, css

I have a pure DIV table using the display: table, table-row, table-cell style of format.
I have the whole table scrolling, but the header row, scrolls as well as the detail rows.

Are there methods available to indicate that the header row (1st row) should not scroll?

Example:

```
    <style>
      .content {overflow: auto;}
      .table { display: table;}
      .row {display: table-row;}
      .cell {display: table-cell;}
    </style>

    ...
<div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">header</div>
        <div class="cell">data</div>
        <div class="cell">row</div>
        <div class="cell">here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">...</div>
        <div class="cell">data</div>
        <div class="cell">row</div>
        <div class="cell">here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">...</div>
        <div class="cell">data</div>
        <div class="cell">row</div>
        <div class="cell">here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd be able to allow the data rows (rows 2 and 3 etc...) to scroll, while the header row (row 1) remains at the top.

Yes - I could do this via HTML  etc... but for various reasons want to try to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
section {
 position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 37px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
  
}
.table{display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey; border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;}
.cell , .cell-header{ display:table-cell; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 25px;}
.row{ display:table-row;}
.row:first-child{height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;}
 .row:first-child div {
    border: none;
}

.cell + .cell {
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
.row:first-child .cell-header div{
 position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -25px;
    line-height: normal;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.row:first-child .cell-header {
  height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table">
      
        <div class="row">
         <div class="cell-header">
            Table attribute name
            <div>Table attribute name</div>
         </div>
         <div class="cell-header">
            Value
            <div>Value</div>
         </div>
         <div class="cell-header">
            Description
            <div>Description</div>
         </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">align</div>
          <div class="cell">left, center, right</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">bgcolor</div>
          <div class="cell">rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">border</div>
          <div class="cell">1,""</div>
          <div class="cell">Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellpadding</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellspacing</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">frame</div>
          <div class="cell">void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">rules</div>
          <div class="cell">none, groups, rows, cols, all</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">summary</div>
          <div class="cell">text</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">width</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels, %</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</div>
        </div>
  
  
  
   <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellpadding</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellspacing</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">frame</div>
          <div class="cell">void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">rules</div>
          <div class="cell">none, groups, rows, cols, all</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">summary</div>
          <div class="cell">text</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">width</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels, %</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</div>
        </div> <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellpadding</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellspacing</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">frame</div>
          <div class="cell">void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">rules</div>
          <div class="cell">none, groups, rows, cols, all</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">summary</div>
          <div class="cell">text</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">width</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels, %</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</div>
        </div> <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellpadding</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellspacing</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">frame</div>
          <div class="cell">void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">rules</div>
          <div class="cell">none, groups, rows, cols, all</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">summary</div>
          <div class="cell">text</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">width</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels, %</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</div>
        </div> <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellpadding</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellspacing</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">frame</div>
          <div class="cell">void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">rules</div>
          <div class="cell">none, groups, rows, cols, all</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">summary</div>
          <div class="cell">text</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">width</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels, %</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</div>
        </div> <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellpadding</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">cellspacing</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">frame</div>
          <div class="cell">void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">rules</div>
          <div class="cell">none, groups, rows, cols, all</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">summary</div>
          <div class="cell">text</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">width</div>
          <div class="cell">pixels, %</div>
          <div class="cell">Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</div>
        </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll
 }
```

`top`, `left`, `bottom` and `width` maintain according to you.

and `overflow-y: scroll;` you not have put `overflow-y: hidden;`